# как отобразить полный url в include

Tags: php, include

Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы на сайте отображался полный (или же просто поддерживался формат `1.php/?tag=`) url.

я пишу

```php
<?
  include ("1.php/?tag=1");
?>
```

но мне выдает ошибку:

```
Warning: include(1.php/?tag=1): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 1.php on line 19

Warning: include(): Failed opening '1.php/?tag=1' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/php-5.6.40/share/pear') in 1.php on line 19
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: не путайте обращения к файловой системе с обращениями к вэб-серверу. `?tag=` это часть хттп протокола. include это подключения файлов. Если в вашем проекте нет какого-то  общего класса для работы с запросом, то в целом вы в любом месте кода можете получить сии параметры через глобальный `$_GET['tag']`.

Answer (score 0):

Параметры после вопросительного знака (**?key=value...**) это фишка HTTP и поэтому то что вы делаете не может работать. Если вам очень хочется, то вы можете сами установить нужные значения для переменной **$_GET**:

```php
$_GET["tag"] = 1;
include "1.php";
```

что является плохой практикой и поэтому я вам советую просто создать и использовать другую переменную, например **$get**:

```php
$get = [
    "tag" => 1
];
include "1.php"; // И в этом скрипте использовать $get вместо $_GET
```

P.s.Ещё хочу сказать что скобки у include (require, require_once, echo и т.п.) не обязательны, а также не стоит указывать слеш (/) в пути, поскольку 1.php это файл, а не директория.

Comment: пиздец зачем я зашел только сейчас